# Bootstrap navbar responsive Logo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this problem with a logo on my bootstrap page, i'm trying my best to make a logo on my navbar stay at the center of the navbar, and stay responsive as i shrink the window, but the navbar text goes behind the image as i shrink the window, and when i click on the dropdown button when it shows, my logo just stays at the top of the page.I need it to move with the dropdown effect and stay glued to the bottom of the navbar, here is my bootstrap code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" id="main">
    <div class="container">
    <img src="images/LogoTango2.png" alt="tango" class="logo">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">начало</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button></div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" id="right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="zakuski.html">цех за закуски</a></li>
                <li><a href="opakovka.html">опаковка</a></li>
                <li><a href="gostilnica.html" id="gostilnica">гостилница</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">контакт</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And that is my css of the logo:

```
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

If you find anything, please notify me, i'll be really thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use position absolute. If you do so you will have to control the behavior on your own with the window.resize event.

If you want the logo at the buttom then put it in the bottom without the position absolute.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" id="main">
<div class="container">

<div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">начало</a>

<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button></div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" id="right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="zakuski.html">цех за закуски</a></li>
            <li><a href="opakovka.html">опаковка</a></li>
            <li><a href="gostilnica.html" id="gostilnica">гостилница</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">контакт</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <img src="images/LogoTango2.png" alt="tango" class="logo">
</div>
</div>

.logo {

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: It did get to the bottom, but the navbar got bigger and the image didnt go to the center, it just says on the left side, taking space and making the navbar bigger,it musnt be part of it.

Comment: Just modify the css to make it fit the way you like without using the position absolute. Try margin:0 auto; to center it.

Comment: the image wont move, no matter what i do. it just stays on the left side

Comment: nevermind, forgot to add the ";" at the end, the margin thing you said worked out, thanks a bunch!